# Is it natural to say "The food is sticking to the inner side of the bottle wall, get it out/off"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Normally, people stick a label or some instruction to/on the outer side of a bottle wall.

Say, you accidentally drop some food on the innter side of a bottle wall of a bottle.

Is it natural to say "**The food is sticking to the inner side of the bottle wall, get it out/off**"?

or do we just simple say "**The food is sticking to the inside of the bottle, get it out/off**"

But "**the inside of a bottle might refer to the empty space inside the bottle**" but I want to talk about "**the inner side of the bottle wall**"

Comment: As usual, you are trying to go into too much detail. Food cannot stick to empty space, so there is no need to explain that you mean 'the inner side of the wall'. A native speaker would probably say something like "There's some food stuck inside the bottle - make sure you wash it thoroughly."

Comment: **Bottle wall** sounds very formal, like what you would say if you were a manufacturer and specifically needed to distinguish the wall from the neck or the base.